# Is there a way to set content with Tailwind css?

Tags: css, css-selectors, tailwind-css

I have to change some styling from css to tailwind but one rule seems to be impossible.

For example, having the following rule which adds an `/` between the elements of an ordered list.

```
.breadcrumb ol li:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: '/';
}
```

Is it possible to make it with tailwind? There is something in the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#transforming-content) but seems too complicated.

Comment: What's stopping you from adding your own style rules that set `content:` on `::after`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the `JIT` mode enabled

then you can do

```
<div class="before:content-['/'] before:block ...">
```

[Here's the link to the docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#content-utilities)